# What does mt -f /dev/st0 erase do exactly on a tape drive?

Tags: hardware, utilities, delete, tape

What does

```
mt -f /dev/st0 erase
```

do exactly with a (LTO-6) tape drive at `/dev/st0`?

It takes hours and seems to write many times.
Does it write random data on the tape several times to delete the contents in a secure way?
Will it delete the magnetic servo tracks?

Comment: With QIC tapes it would basically degauss the tape, i.e. not write random data but use a alternating current through the head to wipe the magnetism. It would sometimes help if writing to a tape gave errors. I have no experience what happens with LTO when erasing.

Comment: I think it is doing so called long erase - writes zeros to the whole tape. I think with LTO it wouldn't degauss the tape as per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Tape-Open): _Using a bulk eraser (or otherwise exposing the cartridge to a strong magnetic field) will erase the servo tracks along with the data tracks, rendering the cartridge unusable_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the version of `mt-st`, however, [this](https://github.com/iustin/mt-st/blob/0442de1f7c7aa07416df092645bc0c18dcb61cba/mt.1) repository performs long erase. Your `mt-st` also performed this, considering the amount of time.

Here is a quote from man page:

> Erase the tape. Note that this is a long erase, which on modern
> (high-capacity) tapes can take many hours, and which usually can't be
> aborted.

First, long erase sets EOD to the current position, according to LTO SCSI [Reference](https://render-prd-trops.events.ibm.com/sites/default/files/support/ssg/ssgdocs.nsf/0/4d430d4b4e1f09b18525787300607b1d/%24FILE/LTO%20SCSI%20Reference%20%28EXTERNAL%20-%2020171024%29.pdf). Then, it writes Data Set Separator (DSS) pattern from the new EOD to the end of the current partition (EOP). DSS is a repeated binary pattern `100 000 000`, according to LTO [Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-319.pdf) from ECMA.

Thus, if you invoke `mt -f /dev/st0 erase` at BOT position and there is only one partition in the tape, then the drive writes EOD at BOT position and then start to over-write data with binary pattern of `100 000 000 100 000 000 100 000 000 ...` until EOP. This can take many hours depending on capacity and transfer rate. For example, LTO-6 native capacity is 2.5TB and write speed is 160MB/sec. It will take (2,500,000MB/160MB/sec) = 15,625sec = 4.3h to complete.